# Array with two awk input files

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have two files, one with `NF=7` and the other has `NF=47`

I need to check the number of occurrences of `$2` in the file with `NF=7`. If the count is `<=2`, then I need to make an array from the same file containing `arr1[$1]=$1`

For this action I used the following code:

```
awk -F"," '{if(NF==7){arr[$2]++}}END{for(i in a){if(arr[i]<=2){print $0}}}'
```

For the action of the second file, I need to match `$1` from the `arr[$1]=$1` taken from the first file with `$1` from the second file.

Please find below example:

File1:

```
1,111,,,,,,
2,111,,,,,,
3,100,,,,,,
4,111,,,,,,
```

File2:

```
1,799,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2,899,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
3,999,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Output:

```
3,999,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare [`NR` with `FNR`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Auto_002dset.html#Auto_002dset) to distinguish between processing the first or the subsequent files. This is because `FNR` is reset per file, while `NR` is the running tally. Therefore, only during the processing of the first file will the condition `NR==FNR` be satisfied.

To process the 'shorter' file, which has to be first...

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{mapper[$1]=$2;counter[$2]++}...'
```

Then, to process the 'longer' file to make it print when your condition satisfies...

```
awk -F, 'NR!=FNR&&counter[mapper[$1]]<=2'
```

Putting both together:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{mapper[$1]=$2;counter[$2]++}NR!=FNR&&counter[mapper[$1]]<=2'
```

By default, `awk` prints the entire line when the selection criteria matches, so simply specifying `NR!=FNR&&counter[mapper[$1]]<=2` will be enough.