# Replace field in one file based on match with a different field in another file

Tags: text-processing

appreciate any help with this task:

File A has 4 fields and has 90K lines.  The first field (column 1) has a value that needs to be changed if criteria below met. The fourth field (column 4) has the data referenced in File B.  The data in File A are tab separated DNS records:

```
Owner IN Type RData
```

FileA:

```
hostname1 IN A 10.10.20.1 
hostname2 IN A 10.10.20.2 
hostname3 IN A 10.10.20.3
```

FileB:

```
10.10.20.1 
10.10.20.2 
10.10.20.58 
10.10.21.245 
10.10.23.7
```

File B is single column (one field) and 1400 lines.  The data in File B are IP addresses.

Requirement: 
For every line in File B, replace the contents of the the first field in File A if the fourth field in File A matches.

In English:
For every IP that's listed in File B, replace the Owner value in File A with a specific value.

Comment: I want to answer your question, but can you add some samples of both files please?

Comment: File A:
`hostname1 IN A 10.10.20.1`
`hostname2 IN A 10.10.20.2`
`alias2 IN CNAME hostname2`
`hostname3 IN A 10.10.20.3`
...
  


File B:
`10.10.20.1`
`10.10.20.2`
`10.10.20.58`
`10.10.21.245`
`10.10.23.7`

Comment: what is the value of field1 from fileA will be?

Comment: I need to change hostname to reserved.

Comment: what can you program in? Perl? Python? Ruby?

Comment: @Skaperen, 
Simple bash shell scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*modifying from my answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/222694/44356)...*)

You can compare [`NR` with `FNR`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Auto_002dset.html#Auto_002dset) to distinguish between processing the first or the subsequent files. This is because `FNR` is reset per file, while `NR` is the running tally. Therefore, only during the processing of the first file will the condition `NR==FNR` be satisfied.

To process FileB first...

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=1}'
```

Setting the value to a 'dummy' one like `1` is good enough.

Then, to process FileA...

```
awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}NR!=FNR{if(a[$4]){$1="Reserved"};print}'
```

Here, the output field separator `OFS` is set as `FS` to preserve the formatting when `awk` reconstructs the full line (`$0`).

Putting both together:

```
awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}NR==FNR{a[$1]=1}NR!=FNR{if(a[$4]){$1="Reserved"};print}' FileB FileA
```

If you want it to be slightly more *terse*...

```
awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}NR==FNR{a[$1]=1;next}a[$4]{$1="Reserved"}1' FileB FileA
```

`next` is used in the processing of the *first* file to skip the final printing indicated by (the final) `1`, which is a shortcut of doing `{print $0}`. With this, we can shift the condition `a[$4]` (i.e. `true` if it exist in `r`) 'out' to be the condition for determining whether we need to change `$1` to `"Reserved"` or not.

Comment: Thanks guys - I've tried these and all give me this error: 

    `awk: fatal: cannot open file `FileB,' for reading (No such file or directory)`
    
 P.S. Sorry for the poor formatting - can't get code to work...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it through `awk`:

```
awk -F"\t" '{if(NF==1){arr[$1]=$1}else{if(arr[$4]==$4){$1="Reserved"}{print $0}}}' fileB, FileA
```

> The constant variable `NF` indicates the number of fields in file, in this code the `awk` will read the FileB first, and put all its data in an array called `arr`, in FileA, if the fourth field `$4` = the array value (IP Address), then it will replace the host name with reserved.

from your samples, this will output:

```
Reserved IN A 10.10.20.1 
Reserved IN A 10.10.20.2 
hostname3 IN A 10.10.20.3
```